# using asynctask in another class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm have written some code using asynctask in an activity. But want the same code to be reused in the service class which is written on separate java file. I tried to write the code in a separate java file so that I can use it on both. But it didn't workout for asynctask. Are there any way to do so. Please provide some tutorial of it, if any. Thanks. The code goes like this.

MainActivity.java

```
//import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    protected static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    protected static final String TAG_CID = "cid";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    JSONArray products = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    public static String url = "http://ensignweb.com/sandbox/app/comment11.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startService(new Intent(this, UpdateService.class));
        new Messages().execute();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,UpdateService.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000, pIntent);        

    }

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        new Messages().execute();
    }
    //Belongs to update service
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
//      stopService(new Intent(this, UpdateService.class));
    }

    class Messages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ProgressDialog dialog = null;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dialog.setTitle("Progressing");
            dialog.setMessage("be patient");
            JSONParser JSP = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = JSP.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try{
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                for(int i = products.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String cid = c.getString(TAG_CID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_CID, cid);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    contactList.add(map);
                    Log.d("value", contactList.toString());
                }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
//          dialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { TAG_NAME,}, new int[] {
                            R.id.name});
            AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear , why its not working, is there some error or what , please explain ?

Comment: Oh. Sorry Let me post the code

Comment: Can I make a separate java file using the code inside "doinbackgound" and use that java class inside asynctask. I tried but didn't work out.

Comment: You can, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need an `AsyncTask` for a service. However, you can do that but you have to make sure that you aren't trying to execute it while it is running from the other activity. Also, they will need to send it the same type of parameters. Generally, you will be better off creating separate tasks for the different classes that need it but it can work. To be safe, you would want to call `cancel()` on the `AsyncTask` when you destroy the activity to make sure it isn't running when you call it from the other class. Other than that, we would need to see the code for the `AsyncTask` and how you are calling it from both classes.

**Edit**

You can create a separate class that extends `AyncTask` and call that from your activity. The nice thing about an inner class is that you have access to the member variables. Another problem you have is trying to update your `progressBar` from your `doInBackground()`. You can't manipulate the `UI` from there. You can from the other 3 `AsyncTask` methods though (`onProgressUpdate()`, `onPostExecute()`, and `onPreExecute()`).

To create a separate class file for `AsyncTask`, create a constructor to accept a context so you have a way to manipulate your `Activity UI`

```
Public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask
{

private Context context; 

public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

// Add your AsyncTask methods and logic
//you can use your context variable in onPostExecute() to manipulate activity UI
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use asynchTask in service, This work can be done through intentService that

Creates a default worker thread that executes all intents delivered to onStartCommand() separate from your application's main thread.

```
        public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {

  /** 
 * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
  * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
 */
  public HelloIntentService() {
     super("HelloIntentService");
   }

  /**
   * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
   * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
  * stops the service, as appropriate.
   */
 @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
  // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000;
  while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
      synchronized (this) {
          try {
              wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
      }
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the reference , 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html